# Filtering a non-activerecord model the right way

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

So i have an api that i can query and return a list of results. my app then processes the results into activerecord like objects in an array. I display these objects in a view in their entirety but i also want to filter the results down.

What is the best way to do this?

Currently, i'm doing something like this:

**view**

```
= form_tag path(resource), method: :get, class: "form-inline", role: "form" do
 .col-sm-3
   = label_tag "See unlimited usage only?"
   .clearfix
   = select_tag "usage", options_for_select(resource.class::USAGE, params[:usage]), class: "form-control", prompt: "All usage limits"
```

**controller**

```
def show
  @media_deals = resource.media_deals
  if params[:usage].present?
    filter = params[:usage]
    if filter == "unlimited"
      @media_deals = @media_deals.find_all{|d| d.download_limit_display.casecmp("Unlimited") == 0}
    elsif filter == "limited"
      @media_deals = @media_deals.find_all{|d| d.download_limit_display.casecmp("Unlimited") != 0}
    end
  end
end
```

Bear in mind that there will be more than one filter not just the one shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, so far you're doing pretty good, there's nothing wrong doing it that way, but I've got a couple suggestions on how to make it better.
First of all, especially if you plan on using several filters, organize them in `Proc`s. Like this for example:

```
{
  unlimited: Proc.new {|d| d.download_limit_display.casecmp("Unlimited") == 0},
  limited: Proc.new {|d| d.download_limit_display.casecmp("Unlimited") != 0}
}
```

This way you can bring all your filters in one place and collect them depending on wich ones you need and then go with an `each` loop like this:

```
filters.each {|filter| @media_deals.find_all! &filter}
```

**UPDATE**

OK, so for the full cycle. Here's what your view could look like.

```
= form_tag path(resource), method: :get, class: "form-inline", role: "form" do
  .col-sm-3
    = label_tag "See unlimited usage only?"
     .clearfix
     = select_tag "filters[usage]", options_for_select(resource.class::USAGE, params[:filters][:usage] if params[:filters].present?)), class: "form-control", prompt: "All usage limits"
  .col-sm-3
    = label_tag "Filter by date"
     .clearfix
     = select_tag "filters[usage]", options_for_select(resource.class::USAGE, params[:filters][:usage] if params[:filters].present?)), class: "form-control", prompt: "All dates"
```

And here's your controller.

```
def show
  @media_deals = resource.media_deals
  filters.each {|filter| @media_deals.select! &filter} if params[:filters].present?
end

private 

def all_filters
  {
    unlimited: Proc.new {|d| d.download_limit_display.casecmp("Unlimited") == 0},
    limited: Proc.new {|d| d.download_limit_display.casecmp("Unlimited") != 0},
    newest: Proc.new {|d| d.created_at <= 1.day.ago },
    recent: Proc.new {|d| d.created_at <= 4.days.ago },
    oldest: Proc.new {|d| d.created_at > 1.year.ago }
  }
end

def filters
  params[:filters].values.map {|f| all_filters[f] if f}.select &:present?
end
```

Just to give you a sence of what's going on. I'd suggest going a step further and moving that set of filters (the `all_filters` method) to the resource itself and maybe breaking it up into a hash of hashes if the naming gets messy.

Comment: Could you give an example of how this would be implemented from view to controller please?

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a go

Comment: would you be able to explain this `filters.each {|filter| @media_deals.select! &filter}` please? there part i don't understand / haven't seen before is `select! &filter`. What does `&filter` mean, what does it do? thanks

Comment: @Robbo, 
`select!` is the same as `select` except that it modifies the object itself rather then just yielding the result. `&filter` sends the Proc object as a block to the `select!` method instead of using it as an argument, wich select does not need.